# 2 very fast and simple queries are terribly slow when merged together

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-performance, mysql-5.7

I have these 2 tables. I'm trying to look for the groups the user with id 1 has joined.
Here are 10 rows of each table (just to show their layout):

PostTable (57,272 rows, primary key id):

```
+----+---------+
| id | groupid |
+----+---------+
|  0 |       1 |
|  1 |       1 |
|  3 |       1 |
|  4 |       1 |
|  5 |       1 |
|  9 |       1 |
| 10 |       1 |
| 13 |       1 |
| 15 |       1 |
| 17 |       1 |
+----+---------+
```

JoinedGroupsTable (258,404 rows, unique index userid,groupid):

```
+--------+---------+--------+
| id     | groupid | userid |
+--------+---------+--------+
| 258010 |       1 |      1 |
| 258484 |       6 |      1 |
|    172 |       1 |      2 |
|    173 |       2 |      2 |
|    174 |       3 |      2 |
|    175 |       4 |      2 |
|    176 |       5 |      2 |
|    177 |       6 |      2 |
|    178 |       8 |      2 |
|    179 |       9 |      2 |
+--------+---------+--------+
```

When I try to run this query, it finished in almost 3 seconds which is really slow:

```
SELECT * FROM posttable p 
WHERE groupid in (SELECT groupid FROM joinedgroupstable WHERE userid=1)
ORDER BY p.ID DESC LIMIt 25;
```

I've also tried to use INNER JOIN rather than WHERE IN, but ended up with roughly the same result:

```
SELECT * FROM posttable p 
INNER JOIN joinedgroupstable jg ON userid=1 AND jg.groupid=p.groupid
ORDER BY p.ID DESC LIMIt 25;
```

Here is the EXPLAIN SELECT for both queries (Same result for both queries):

```
|| *id* || *select_type* || *table* || *partitions* || *type* || *possible_keys* || *key* || *key_len* || *ref* || *rows* || *filtered* || *Extra* ||
|| 1 || SIMPLE || jg ||  || ref || UserID_GroupID,userid || UserID_GroupID || 4 || const || 2 || 100.00 || Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort ||
|| 1 || SIMPLE || p ||  || ref || groupid || groupid || 4 || thyra.jg.groupid || 60 || 100.00 ||  ||
```

The thing is that running each query on its own is super fast:

```
SELECT * FROM posttable p ORDER BY p.ID DESC LIMIt 25;

SELECT * FROM joinedgroupstable WHERE userid=1
```

What could be wrong considering each query runs super fast on its own but slow when merged?

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use?

Comment: Can you include how many rows each table has?

Comment: @stickybit 5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1

Comment: @TheImpaler just did

Comment: If I had to guess, it would be the order by limit that is the problem.

Comment: If you have a large number of posts records, that ordering and limit could be killing you. If you have an indexed datetime/timestamp field (and don't mind eliminating older results entirely) you could filter to only posts from the last X days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `EXISTS` instead that could be also perform better :

```
select p.*
from posttable p 
where exists (select 1 
              from joinedgroupstable jg
              where jg.groupid = p.groupid and jg.userid = 1
              )
order by p.id desc
limit 25;
```

Comment: Weird. This fixed it without having to remove order by p.id desc. So is joining the joinedgroupstable causing the order by to slow down? Anyway this also worked so I'll accept this answer too. Thank you!

Comment: @Krestek I am guessing this form allows MYSQL to use the index on `p.id` to grab the latest posts and then check whether they are in an appropriate group. The correlated query most likely gets executed/evaluated separately for each candidate `p`, but in this case that ends up being cheaper than getting every relevant p and then sorting those for the most recent ones.

Comment: @Uueerdo Ah so basically it repeats the "exists" query on every p row which shouldn't be the go to in general but it works here because it picks less rows of p for sorting. Got it, thanks :>

Comment: Well, let's see the `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: @Krestek Yes, that would be my _guess_.

Answer (score 4):

If your question is simplified and your `PostTable` contains more columns than you showed us, your `ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...` clause is causing a lot of wasted sorting.

You can do a so-called "deferred join."  First get the appropriate id values, then use them to retrieve the rows.

```
select p.* 
  from posttable p
  join (
       select a.id
       from posttable a
       join joinedgroupstable g on a.groupid = g.groupid
      where g.userid = 1
      order by a.id desc
      limit 25
     ) sel on sel.id = p.id
order by p.id desc
limit 25;
```

This confines the expensive `ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...` operation to just the `id` column, then uses the chosen `id` values to hit your main table only 25 times.

Comment: This was it! I just checked again and the ORDER BY was causing the problem. Your solution solved it though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To speed up the first query add the following indexes:

```
create index ix1 on joinedgroupstable (userid, groupid);

create index ix2 on PostTable (id);
```

The second query looks wrong to me.

Comment: It is still as slow after running these queries. There was already a unique index (userid, groupid) and id is pk in posttable

Comment: @Krestek - If `(userid, groupid)` is unique, them make it the `PRIMARY KEY` and get rid of `id`.  This may provide a speedup due to the PK being 'clustered' with the data.

Comment: @RickJames I'm actually using the id in other queries for ordering sake, though I'll remove PKs from tables I'm not using it in, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Different answer:

```
create index ix10 on joinedgroupstable (userid);

create index ix11 on posttable (groupid);

select p.* 
  from posttable p
  join joinedgroupstable g on p.groupid = g.groupid
  where g.userid = 1
  order by p.id desc
  limit 25;
```